# eas build --platform android VS expo build:android -t apk

Tags: react-native, expo, apk, bundle

I am generating APK using `eas build --platform android` and  `expo build:android -t apk`.
Both generate apps but the `eas build` generated app crashes while the `expo build` app works fine. There is no difference in code. Not able to check why it happens. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: I got my app crash when open in physical android app with eas build. Not with expo build. If you find any fix, tell me.

Comment: I resolved this by removing the dependency that the expo was managing itself.
e.g "react-native-screens": "~3.8.0". My i can export .apk and .aab using eas build.

Comment: are you saying that I should remove all dependencies that expo was managing before building with 'eas'?

Comment: Fix all the warnings that you get in the console.

Comment: Actually, I don't get any warning in the console while building with eas. The apk file on pyhsical device just crashes when open. I install most of dependencies with `expo install dependency_name`.

Comment: Can you share at which screen your app crashes and what export statements you have in there and share the package.json

Comment: if you are asking me I asked my question here. https://stackoverflow.com/q/72412416/16326242

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by manually installing some dependency that EXPO is managing itself.

Building `.apks` using EXPO command `expo build:android -t apk` never crashed on the physical device, but when I switched to EAS command `eas build --platform android` the app crashed on physical devices.

Dependency e.g "react-native-screens": "~3.8.0". Now i can export `.apk` and `.aab` using EAS command `eas build --platform android`

Other issues like camera and gallery permission are also managed by EXPO if you don't mention them.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly? Expo has dependencies, and instead of just running `npm install expo` which will install those dependencies as well, you add the dependencies such as react-native-screens as your own dependencies to your own package.json? Do you install those dependencies on their own before you do a "npm install" (which will install everything in your package.json)?

Comment: Also, in my comment I use `npm install` when I should be saying `npx expo install`, But I think you have to do npm install until you have expo installed. haha if that makes sense.

Comment: oh wait, after reading your comment again.. are you saying to remove the dependencies that you added to your project that are actually already included with expo?

Comment: Meaning I remove things like "expo-application", "expo-file-system", "expo-constants" from my own package.json? I'm doing that now.

Comment: expo build:android has been discontinued (January 4, 2023).

The Classic Build service is deprecated. The final version to support it was Expo SDK 46.

Please migrate to EAS Build to continue building your app.

Answer (score -1):

This may be because of the Expo SDK version.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What do you mean by that? Is this due to the expo-cli version being wrong? I'm running into issues. I noticed my expo-cli is a year out of date.