# Expo EAS build android apk crash on physical device

Tags: android, react-native, expo, apk

I built `eas -p android --profile luna`. Then, I downloaded into physical device. When open it, the app crashes after showing splash screen. Expo SDK 45.0.0. 
I tried to change `eas.json` profile. Here is what I tried.

```
"luna": {
  "android": {
    "buildType": "apk",
    "distribution": "internal"
  }
}

"luna": {
  "android": {
    "buildType": "apk",
    "distribution": "internal",
    "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
  }
}

"luna": {
  "android": {
    "buildType": "apk"
  }
},

"luna": {
  "android": {
    "buildType": "apk",
    "developmentClient": true
  }
},
```

DevelopmentClient one can be opened but not the one I want. 
Can someone tell or direct or advice me

1. How to build apk with eas for physical device
2. Should I downgrade to Expo SDK 44.0.0 and use `expo build:android`?
3. How to create apk for physical device without expo (like ejecting expo)
4. `expo build` classic build will be removed completely. Should I build react-native app without expo in the future?

my package.json file.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.1.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "8.2.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.6",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.15.1",
    "expo-sqlite": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "firebase": "^9.8.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.2.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^13.1.2",
    "react-native-pager-view": "5.4.15",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "victory-native": "^36.4.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~0.9.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.67.7",
    "babel-plugin-root-import": "^6.6.0"
  },
```

Comment: can you try `eas build -p android --profile preview` for .apk and `eas build --platform android ` for .aab

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try to log your errors. The first step I would recommend you to take is connecting your device (having USB debugging active) to your PC, go to where your `adb` is installed, open a CMD/PowerShell window in that folder, run `adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V`, and try to open the app that crashes to see what it logs when it does.

An issue that I've had was that there was a problem with some dependency that EAS was adding during the build, so I installed it (`react-native-reanimated@^2.8.0`) separately through `npm i`, and then my build worked with EAS.

Comment: This gave me idea. I initiated new Expo project and build apk without changing any code and installed in device. It works. Thank you. I wonder how many dependencies there are that EAS handled while building and make the app crashes. It would be perfection if someone do research on complete list of that dependencies. Also, did you install `npm i --save react-native-reanimated@^2.8.0` with specific version? How do you know which version is suitable for current SDK? With many thanks, @whitedark

Comment: I just installed `react-native-reanimated` and hoped for the best. I've specified the version here because this is the version that worked for me. I have SDK 45 for Expo, and maybe ^2.8.0 fits this version better than the one installed automatically by EAS (when there isn't already a version installed in advance before trying to build the app).

Comment: @gusti the command `adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V` gives me this error

```bash
zsh: no matches found: *:S

```

Comment: @Sudarshan, run first `adb shell`, then inside adb shell run `logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V`

Comment: I did this .. but i got this error 

[stderr] 

A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-reanimated'.

[stderr] 

> Could not get unknown property 'rnMinorVersion' for project ':react-native-reanimated' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is regarding **expo-update** package.

If you this expo-update package install than you need to run **eas update:configure** command and if it doesn't completes automatically than follow the instruction printed by this command manually.

You may get more from this official expo page: https://docs.expo.dev/eas-update/migrate-from-classic-updates/

Hope it helps !! Wasted a 2 whole days figuring it out.

Comment: And it's such weird behaviour as well... I created a new dev build (after installing `expo-updates`) and, both, my current Android phone that I use every day and my Android simulator had no issues. However, my old Android device kept crashing on start up. You helped lead me in the right direction! To anyone coming here in the future, the full command that I ended up using is: `rm -rf node_modules android ios && npm ci && eas build:configure && eas update:configure && npx expo-doctor && npx expo prebuild && eas build --profile development --platform android --clear-cache`

Answer (score 2):

To see just the log of your app with adb, use:
`adb logcat -e "appname"`

You can also filter Errors:
`adb logcat -e "appname" | grep Error`

Answer (score 2):

For me, my issue was that development builds worked fine, but when building a production aab, it would instantly crash after the splash screen (like you)

As @gusti mentioned, it was a problem with the `react-native-reanimated` package (which I had never manually installed btw). I *uninstalled* it off npm, then rebuilt, and everything ran fine.

Not sure if this the best way to go about fixing this, but it saved me a lot of time.

Comment: I was also facing the same issue removing react-native-reanimated package solved my issue. Thanks, buddy

Comment: Glad its fixed bhai

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. First I ran `npx expo-doctor` then it told me to:

1. Fix Package dependencies issues.
2. Field: Android.adaptiveIcon.foregroundImage - image should be square, but the file at './assets/logo.png' has dimensions 150x148.
3. Field: icon - image should be square, but the file at './assets/logo.png' has dimensions 150x148.

So I fixed all these. and then again ran `npx expo-doctor` and it was then fixed.

Answer (score 0):

as gusti mentioned you need to debug your application then you can locate the problem and fix it.
For me the problem was that I needed to install a package called "react-native-safe-area-context" by:

- `npm install react-native-safe-area-context` then run `expo doctor --fix-dependencies` to make it compatible with your sdk version.
- or directly run `expo install react-native-safe-area-context`

if it didn't work try to run `expo update` it will upgrade the sdk version and reinstall all the packages to make them compatible with the new version.

This was my problem you might face a different one, but you just need to read the error message and fix it.

Comment: hey med, how you figured out that `react-native-safe-area-context` this package is causing error?

In my case logcat is printing tremendous logs when I used it as

`adb -s --device_id-- logcat`

is there anything else I have to do ?

Comment: Try to read the error message it must be somewhere in the logs. Otherwise you can share your logs with us and we'll try to figure out the problem

Comment: For my app suspicious error logs  are 
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jack-sparroow/bfba7add4d80b5b0e403f5b4759a7f67/raw/5d694c8f2157dfc88ccef5b25b25eaf07c47a112/gistfile1.txt

Comment: hey, I got this error statement in adb-logcat

```bash

E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument

```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what helped me. Initially, I made [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72412416/expo-eas-build-android-apk-crash-on-physical-device#comment137252942_76936543), but then I started running into just odd one off crashes and I was even able to reproduce the original crash problem that I had.

This led me to believe that I didn't actually "fix" anything, and decided to keep digging further. I ended up reinstalling all my dependencies with `npx expo install`. So if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76936543/2891356) doesn't do it for you, try doing what I did below.

Jot down all your dependencies (not dev or peer dependencies) and form them into a nice one-liner, then uninstall all these packages, then reinstall `expo@whatever-version-you-had`, and then `npx expo install` all the other libraries.

So if your `expo` version is, say, 49, and your whole dependency list is:

```bash
react react-native expo axios
                   ^^^^ notice this here
```

Then run the following command:

```bash
npm uninstall react react-native expo axios && npm i expo@49 && npx expo install react react-native axios
                                                          ^^
```

It's worth specifying what version of `expo` you had, because if you don't, it'll install whatever latest version is available. I initially didn't specify `expo@49` and it installed `expo@50.0.2`, causing my app to crash due to package compatibility issues.